Oracle Analytics no me permite sumar mismos valores
Este problema es de Oracle Analytics Cloud, por lo que las consultas sql son diferentes.
Tengo una columna con diferentes periodos de pago de nómina "S" por semanas y "Q" por quincenas, etc. necesito crear un gráfico de líneas como el de la imagen pero que en lugar de meses sea por semana
Pero que sea por semana, así creo una nueva columna donde a las "S" dependiendo de su número se le asigna un nuevo nombre como "SEM" y a las "Q" se le asigna el mismo nombre de "SEM" pero dependiendo de que semanas estaban dentro, ejemplo "Q01" = "SEM01", "Q1" = "SEM02", "Q01" = "SEM03" y así.

Entonces se creo el siguiente calculo
CASE WHEN PERIODOF = 'SEM01' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PERIODO =  'S01'  THEN ID_SAP END) + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PERIODO = 'Q01' THEN ID_SAP  END) WHEN PERIODOF = 'SEM02' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PERIODO = 'S02'  THEN ID_SAP END) + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PERIODO = 'Q01' THEN ID_SAP  END) WHEN PERIODOF = 'SEM03' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PERIODO = 'S03'  THEN ID_SAP END) + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PERIODO = 'Q01' THEN ID_SAP  END) WHEN PERIODOF = 'SEM04' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PERIODO = 'S04'  THEN ID_SAP END) + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PERIODO = 'Q02' THEN ID_SAP  END) WHEN PERIODOF = 'SEM05' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PERIODO = 'S05'  THEN ID_SAP END) + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PERIODO = 'Q02' THEN ID_SAP  END) WHEN PERIODOF = 'SEM06' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PERIODO = 'S06'  THEN ID_SAP END) + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PERIODO = 'Q03' THEN ID_SAP  END) WHEN PERIODOF = 'SEM07' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PERIODO = 'S07'  THEN ID_SAP END) + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PERIODO = 'Q03' THEN ID_SAP  END) 

En los puntos más altos es donde se encuentra la suma de empleados semanales y quincenales y los menores solo se cuentan las semanas
El problema es que la suma de las diferentes cosas solo se da en el primer "SEM" que se encuentra dentro de "Q" por lo que mi gráfica es incorrecta.
¿Podrian tener una idea de cómo puedo corregirlo? Gracias
Se sumaran los diferentes id's de cada periodo y se graficara de forma igual, pero tiene muchas variaciones

Siempre ten presente que mayúsculas en internet = GRITAR. Además, si colocas el mouse sobre la etiqueta [programación-bajo-nivel], te percatarás que nada tiene que ver con tu pregunta. Lee [ask], haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

@padaleiana Muchas gracias, por los consejos.
Me di el tiempo de poder revisarlo y ahora ya lo he corregido.
Muchas gracias :)
